# External HTML or a Hidden content

Tags: jquery, html, css

The question might be silly but is the first time I am touching some HTML and CSS in my life so here it goes.
Basically I am trying to find out how I can keep the same  throughout the whole website, it was apparently easy and it's probably easy but I am kind of struggling with that and I am gonna tell you why!

I have got 3 main pages 1 2 3, a nav with link to each page 1, 2, 3 and also a few fullscreen slides that would be shown by itself when called by the thumb.(shown by its own out of the main pages) 
What I was going to do was get one html per each slide, so when clicking on the thumb it brings the slide through its URL, on "slide1.html" for example, I've placed the  same   from my main pages but now targeting the href with the URL of the page however it did not work as I have only one URL for my three main pages I also assume that is not a way to make it.

I had a look in some websites but I am not entirely sure if it'll suit what I want. Would an external html be the a good solution?

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
    <nav>

        <ol>
            <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
        </ol>

    </nav>
```

Page 1

#

```
<div id="page2">
    <p>Page 2</p>

    <li class="thumb">
        <a href="url-slide1">Thumb 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a href="url-slide2">Thumb 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="thumb">
        <a href="url-slide3">Thumb 3</a>
    </li>
</div>

<div id="page3">

    <p>Page 3</p>
</div>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to have all the slides hidden within the page2, so I would call the div from the same html file what would be way easier.

```
   <nav>

        <ol>
            <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
        </ol>

    </nav>


    <div id="page1">
        <p>Page 1</p>
    </div>#

    <div id="page2">
         <p>Page 2</p>
         <li class="thumb">
              <a href="#slides1">Thumb 1</a>
         </li>
          <li class="thumb">
        <a href="#slides2">Thumb 2</a>
          </li>
        <li class="thumb">
        <a href="#slides3">Thumb 3</a>
        </li>
</div>

<div id=slidesWraper>
     <div id=slides1"><div>
     <div id=slides2"><div>
     <div id=slides3"><div>
</div>

<div id="page3">

    <p>Page 3</p>
</div>
```

I hope the link helps http://jsfiddle.net/marco_desi/fJ2yv/ not quite sure.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same sort of thing as a newby, the answer being in the form of a question was "what's wrong with having 3 pages instead of just one?" Soo, don't bother with that, have an html page per percieved page.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working however I am having an issue here. I have a button from a html file "html slides" referencing a div to another html file "html main", but when clicking on the button it's bringing me to another div into the "html main". I really have no idea what's wrong as the button references are right. Any ideas? Here is the link of one page for reference. http://thisismarco.com/dev/html/map.html, the issue is happening on the work button. If somebody has any idea please let me know. Thank you all in advance.